# How to abort makefile if variable not set?

Tags: makefile

How could I abort a make/makefile execution based on a makefile's variable not being set/valued?

I came up with this, but works only if caller doesn't explicitly run a target (i.e. runs `make` only).

```
ifeq ($(MY_FLAG),)
abort:   ## This MUST be the first target :( ugly
    @echo Variable MY_FLAG not set && false
endif

all:
    @echo MY_FLAG=$(MY_FLAG)
```

I think something like this would be a good idea, but didn't find anything in make's manual:

```
ifndef MY_FLAG
.ABORT
endif
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Makefile variable as prerequisite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728810/makefile-variable-as-prerequisite)

Comment: The simplest answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71243186/5172890

Comment: Related feature request: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?63737

Answer (score 412, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Use the [`error` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions):

```makefile
ifndef MY_FLAG
$(error MY_FLAG is not set)
endif
```

Note that the lines must not be indented. More precisely, no tabs must precede these lines.

---

## Generic solution

In case you're going to test many variables, it's worth defining an auxiliary function for that:

```makefile
# Check that given variables are set and all have non-empty values,
# die with an error otherwise.
#
# Params:
#   1. Variable name(s) to test.
#   2. (optional) Error message to print.
check_defined = \
    $(strip $(foreach 1,$1, \
        $(call __check_defined,$1,$(strip $(value 2)))))
__check_defined = \
    $(if $(value $1),, \
      $(error Undefined $1$(if $2, ($2))))
```

And here is how to use it:

```makefile
$(call check_defined, MY_FLAG)

$(call check_defined, OUT_DIR, build directory)
$(call check_defined, BIN_DIR, where to put binary artifacts)
$(call check_defined, \
            LIB_INCLUDE_DIR \
            LIB_SOURCE_DIR, \
        library path)
```

This would output an error like this:

```makefile
Makefile:17: *** Undefined OUT_DIR (build directory).  Stop.
```

### Notes:

The real check is done here:

```makefile
$(if $(value $1),,$(error ...))
```

This reflects the behavior of the `ifndef` conditional, so that a variable defined to an empty value is also considered "undefined". But this is only true for simple variables and explicitly empty recursive variables:

```makefile
# ifndef and check_defined consider these UNDEFINED:
explicitly_empty =
simple_empty := $(explicitly_empty)

# ifndef and check_defined consider it OK (defined):
recursive_empty = $(explicitly_empty)
```

As suggested by @VictorSergienko in the comments, a slightly different behavior may be desired:

> `$(if $(value $1)` tests if the value is non-empty. It's sometimes **OK if the variable is defined with an empty value**. I'd use `$(if $(filter undefined,$(origin $1)) ...`

And:

> Moreover, **if it's a directory and it must exist** when the check is run, I'd use `$(if $(wildcard $1))`. But would be another function.

## Target-specific check

It is also possible to extend the solution so that one can require a variable only if a certain target is invoked.

#### `$(call check_defined, ...)` from inside the recipe

Just move the check into the recipe:

```makefile
foo :
    @:$(call check_defined, BAR, baz value)
```

The leading `@` sign turns off command echoing and `:` is the actual command, a shell [no-op stub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin/3224910#3224910).

#### Showing target name

The `check_defined` function can be improved to also output the target name (provided through the `$@` variable):

```makefile
check_defined = \
    $(strip $(foreach 1,$1, \
        $(call __check_defined,$1,$(strip $(value 2)))))
__check_defined = \
    $(if $(value $1),, \
        $(error Undefined $1$(if $2, ($2))$(if $(value @), \
                required by target `$@')))
```

So that, now a failed check produces a nicely formatted output:

```makefile
Makefile:7: *** Undefined BAR (baz value) required by target `foo'.  Stop.
```

#### `check-defined-MY_FLAG` special target

Personally I would use the simple and straightforward solution above. However, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728810/makefile-variable-as-prerequisite/4731504#4731504) suggests using a special target to perform the actual check. One could try to generalize that and define the target as an implicit pattern rule:

```makefile
# Check that a variable specified through the stem is defined and has
# a non-empty value, die with an error otherwise.
#
#   %: The name of the variable to test.
#   
check-defined-% : __check_defined_FORCE
    @:$(call check_defined, $*, target-specific)

# Since pattern rules can't be listed as prerequisites of .PHONY,
# we use the old-school and hackish FORCE workaround.
# You could go without this, but otherwise a check can be missed
# in case a file named like `check-defined-...` exists in the root 
# directory, e.g. left by an accidental `make -t` invocation.
.PHONY : __check_defined_FORCE
__check_defined_FORCE :
```

Usage:

```makefile
foo :|check-defined-BAR
```

Notice that the `check-defined-BAR` is listed as the [order-only](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) (`|...`) prerequisite.

Pros:

- (arguably) a more clean syntax

Cons:

- One can't specify a custom error message
- Running `make -t` (see [Instead of Executing Recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Instead-of-Execution)) will pollute your root directory with lots of `check-defined-...` files. This is a sad drawback of the fact that pattern rules [can't be declared `.PHONY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095569/when-declaring-the-pattern-rule-as-phony-it-is-not-triggered).

I believe, these limitations can be overcome using some [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) magic and [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) hacks, although I'm not sure it's worth it.

Comment: What exactly? Never used Mac, though I guess it has another implementation of Make installed by default (e.g. BSD Make instead of GNU Make). I'd suggest you to check `make --version` as the first step.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in make 3.81. It always errors, even if the variable is defined (and can be echoed).

Comment: Ah, you need to structure it exactlt as in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @EldarAbusalimov how do I make the requirement `build_target` specific?

Comment: @bibstha I added the options that come in mind, please read the updated answer.

Comment: I'd add a clarification-for-noobies (like me) that ifndef needs to be not indented :) I found that tip somewhere else and suddenly all my errors made sense.

Comment: If 'ifndef needs to be not indented' comment was buried for me.  It would be helpful if the example had a little more to it to show the indentation problem.

Comment: 1. `$(if $(value $1)` tests if the value is non-empty. It's sometimes OK if the variable is defined with an empty value. I'd use `$(if $(filter undefined,$(origin $1)) ...`

Comment: 2. Moreover, if it's a directory and it must exist when the check is run, I'd use `$(if $(wildcard $1))`. But would be another function.

Comment: 3. In `$(foreach`, naming a variable `1` when you already have one (wink) complicates reading. Making it, say, `DIR` or `VALUE` would improve the readability a bit.

Comment: @VictorSergienko 1 and 2. The `$(if $(value $1)` check reflects behavior of the `ifdef` directive, that is, an empty value is also considered undefined.

Comment: @VictorSergienko 3. Naming the iteration variable `DIR` would break a totally correct `$(call check_defined, DIR)` because the iteration variable would shadow the variable being tested. Shadowing the argument 1 seems to me the least evil in this case.

Comment: @VictorSergienko I added some notes, please check that out. Thank you!

Comment: When I use "Generic solution", make warns me `warning: undefined variable '1'` and then `*** Undefined .  Stop.`.  I can't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @GermanLashevich do you use it as suggested, i.e. through `$(call check_defined,...)`, and not $(__check_defined) or something?

Comment: @EldarAbusalimov I run it as `$(call check_defined, MY_FLAG)`. After some debug I figured out that the error occurs if there is `export` directive in the Makefile. And the warning occurs only if `warn-undefined-variables` flag is set.

Comment: The TLDR; solution always errors on `GNU Make 4.2.1` when checking against an externally defined environment variable.

Answer (score 58):

Use the shell function `test`:

```
foo:
    test $(something)
```

Usage:

```
$ make foo
test 
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'foo' failed
make: *** [foo] Error 1
$ make foo something=x
test x
```

Comment: This is what I used when faced with the same issue - thanks, Messa!  I made two slight modifications: 1) I created a `checkforsomething` target that only had the `test` in it and made `foo` dependent on that, and 2) i changed the check to `@if test -z "$(something)"; then echo "helpful error here"; exit 1; fi` instead.  That gave me the ability to add a useful error, and allowed me to make the name of the new target a little more indicative of what went wrong as well.

Comment: With this I get `Makefile:5: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: For compactness I used `test -n "$(something) || (echo "message" ; exit 1)` to avoid the explicit `if`.

Comment: @silgon you are probably indenting using spaces rather than a tab.

Comment: @user295691 you probably want curly braces `{ ... }` instead of parenthasis `( ...  )`, which executes in a subshell

Answer (score 19):

You can use an IF to test:

```
check:
        @[ "${var}" ] || ( echo ">> var is not set"; exit 1 )
```

Result:

```
$ make check
>> var is not set
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'check' failed
make: *** [check] Error 1
```

Comment: `[` is an alias for the command `test`, so this is the same answer as @Messa above.  This is more compact, though, and includes the error message generation.

Comment: This really seems like the cleanest answer for most circumstances.

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity of this answer. The next person reading my Makefile will know what this does, even if they don't know how it works.

Answer (score 13):

Another option:

```
MY_FLAG = $(error Please set this flag)
```

Attempting to use this variable anywhere will cause an error, unless it's overriden from the command line.

To accept environment variables as well, use `?=`:

```
MY_FLAG ?= $(error Please set this flag)
```

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Comment: This is a clean-code answer, but can you f.x. call the `clean` target without setting this variable?

Comment: @Ezbob Yes. You only get the error if you try to read the variable.

Comment: Then this is clearly the best answer, I would say.

Answer (score 9):

For simplicity and brevity:

```
$ cat Makefile
check-%:
        @: $(if $(value $*),,$(error $* is undefined))

bar:| check-foo
        echo "foo is $$foo"
```

With outputs:

```
$ make bar
Makefile:2: *** foo is undefined. Stop.
$ make bar foo="something"
echo "foo is $$foo"
foo is something
```

Comment: can be fooled with `$ touch check-foo; make bar` ... need the check_defined_FORCE trick in other answer

Answer (score 8):

Use the shell error handling for unset variables (note the double `$`):

```
$ cat Makefile
foo:
        echo "something is set to $${something:?}"

$ make foo
echo "something is set to ${something:?}"
/bin/sh: something: parameter null or not set
make: *** [foo] Error 127


$ make foo something=x
echo "something is set to ${something:?}"
something is set to x
```

If you need a custom error message, add it after the `?`:

```
$ cat Makefile
hello:
        echo "hello $${name:?please tell me who you are via \$$name}"

$ make hello
echo "hello ${name:?please tell me who you are via \$name}"
/bin/sh: name: please tell me who you are via $name
make: *** [hello] Error 127

$ make hello name=jesus
echo "hello ${name:?please tell me who you are via \$name}"
hello jesus
```