# Checking if variables are defined in a makefile

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements, environment-variables, gnu-make

I have a GNU Makefile (version 3.81) that looks like the following:

```
.PHONY: SPOneDot

SPOneDot:
    ifndef X
    X=0.05
    $$(info X undefined, changed to $X)
    endif
    ifndef Y
    Y=0.05
    $$(info Y undefined, changed to $Y)
    endif
    python ./Submit3DSP.py -f OneDot.qdt -x $(X) -y $(Y)
```

I execute with the following command line: `make X=0.1 Y=0.1 SPOneDot` but I get the following result:

```
ifndef X
make: ifndef: Command not found
make: *** [SPOneDot] Error 127
```

I've looked in the [makefile documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) and seen [others use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858261/abort-makefile-if-variable-not-set).  Any help is appreciated, it's likely something foolish.

Comment: What kind of make is this? GNU make? BSD? POSIX?

Comment: GNU Make version 3.81 is being used here.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Most likely your make directives **must not be tab indented** but start in the first column.
I also suspect you want `.if(...)` or similar, not plain `ifdef`. It's hard to tell without knowing what `make` implementation you use.

In GNU make, conditional parts are used e.g. like this

```
ifeq ($(CC),gcc)
        $(CC) -o foo $(objects) $(libs_for_gcc)
else
        $(CC) -o foo $(objects) $(normal_libs)
endif
```

The [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditionals) has all the details.

If you really mean to test an **environment** variable (as opposed to a **make variable**), then simply do so in the commands:

```
SPOneDot:
    if test -z "$$X"; then X=0.05; echo "X undefined, changed to $$X"; fi; \
    if test -z "$$Y"; then Y=0.05; echo "Y undefined, changed to $$Y"; fi; \
    python ./Submit3DSP.py -f OneDot.qdt -x $$X -y $$Y
```

Note that `$$` is passed to the shell as a single `$` and everything must be a single command for the shell, hence the semicolons and backslash/newlines.

Comment: I am only interested in these variables if I'm doing this particular target, do I still need them to be unindented?

Comment: Thank you, I learned that you can't put conditionals within a target.  There are clever ways to get around doing this but I will use the environment variable fix.  BTW, you should have a " after echo in both lines to make this work.

Answer (score 6):

If the line begins with a tab, it will be considered part of a recipe for a rule. Extra spaces are allowed and ignored at the beginning of the conditional directive line, but a tab is not allowed.