# Makefile -- error out if variable not set

Tags: makefile

Following advice at [Abort makefile if variable not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858261/abort-makefile-if-variable-not-set) I am attempting to use `ifndef` but it's not working.

Makefile:

```
foo:
        ifndef BAR
        $(error "Must set BAR")
        endif
```

But `make foo BAR=quux` does not work:

```
Makfile:2: *** "Must set BAR". Stop.
```

What gives?  Is it whitespace issue?  Or am I misunderstanding completely?

(I'm using GNU Make)

I tried also:

```
foo:
ifndef BAR
$(error "Must set BAR")
endif
        echo $(BAR)
```

Which seems to sort of work but still causes the `ifndef` to be invoked if a target further down in the Makefile (which does not require the variable to be set) is invoked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically, yes, it's a whitespace problem, but more fundamentally it's a scope problem.

The `ifndef... endif` is a *Make* conditional. So Make will evaluate it before executing any rule. And since the `ifndef` is not part of a recipe, it should not be preceded by a TAB. This works:

```
ifndef BAR
$(error "Must set BAR") # this is a Make error
endif

foo:
ifndef BAR
    echo "Must set BAR" # this is a shell command
    exit 1              # this is another shell command
endif
```

But what you did was this:

```
foo:
    ifndef BAR
    $(error "Must set BAR")
    endif
```

You put a TAB in front of the three lines (`ifndef...`, `$(error...` and `endif`), so Make assumed that those were commands, to be passed to the shell if and when the `foo` recipe was executed. And when Make executed the rule, it expanded the Make-syntax statement `$(error...)` -- and terminated with an error -- before passing anything to the shell.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "if" function this purpose.

`foo : 
     $(if $(BAR),,$(error Must set BAR))`