# What is an efficient/correct way to test that a variable is set in a Makefile for all but the clean rule?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to create a Makefile that enforces (fails if not true) that a variable is set.

Having read [Passing additional variables from command line to make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make) and [Makefile -- error out if variable not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777722/makefile-error-out-if-variable-not-set) and [How to abort makefile if variable not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858261/how-to-abort-makefile-if-variable-not-set) and [If conditions in a Makefile, inside a target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977796/if-conditions-in-a-makefile-inside-a-target), I'm aware of two apparent choices: `make` [conditional functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html), e.g. `$(if condition,then-part[,else-part])`, and "global" conditionals, e.g. `ifndef variable-name`.

My understanding is that a global conditional would effectively be something like this:

```
.PHONY: all, clean

OBJS=lorem.o ipsum.o

ifndef LIBUV_LIB
$(error LIBUV_LIB not set)
endif

all: liblorem.so libipsum.so

liblorem.so: lorem.o
        $(CC) -shared -o $@ $^ -L $(LIBUV_LIB) -luv

libipsum.so: ipsum.o
        $(CC) -shared -o $@ $^ -L $(LIBUV_LIB) -luv

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS) liblorem.so libipsum.so
```

...i.e. existence of `LIBUV_LIB` is evaluated "globally", and I can set it by passing it as a `make` argument:

```
$ make
Makefile:6: *** LIBUV_LIB not set.  Stop.
$
$ make LIBUV_LIB=/usr/local/libuv1.45.0
cc    -c -o lorem.o lorem.c
cc -shared -o liblorem.so lorem.o -L /usr/local/libuv1.45.0 -luv
cc    -c -o ipsum.o ipsum.c
cc -shared -o libipsum.so ipsum.o -L /usr/local/libuv1.45.0 -luv
$
```

This does the job, it just has the annoying effect of needing to be set for the `clean` target, where it's not really relevant:

```
$ make clean
Makefile:6: *** LIBUV_LIB not set.  Stop.
$ make LIBUV_LIB=/usr/local/libuv1.45.0 clean
rm -f lorem.o ipsum.o liblorem.so libipsum.so
$
```

Exploring the conditional function, I came up with this Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all, clean

OBJS=lorem.o ipsum.o

all: liblorem.so libipsum.so

liblorem.so: lorem.o
        $(if $(LIBUV_LIB),,$(error LIBUV_LIB not set))
        $(CC) -shared -o $@ $^ -L $(LIBUV_LIB) -luv

libipsum.so: ipsum.o
        $(if $(LIBUV_LIB),,$(error LIBUV_LIB not set))
        $(CC) -shared -o $@ $^ -L $(LIBUV_LIB) -luv

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS) liblorem.so libipsum.so
```

This also does the job:

```
$ make
cc    -c -o lorem.o lorem.c
Makefile:8: *** LIBUV_LIB not set.  Stop.
$
$ make LIBUV_LIB=/usr/local/libuv1.45.0
cc -shared -o liblorem.so lorem.o -L /usr/local/libuv1.45.0 -luv
cc    -c -o ipsum.o ipsum.c
cc -shared -o libipsum.so ipsum.o -L /usr/local/libuv1.45.0 -luv
$
```

...and seems to circumvent my grievance with needing to specify `LIBUV_LIB` for the `clean` target:

```
$ make clean
rm -f lorem.o ipsum.o liblorem.so libipsum.so
$
```

My gripe now is the repetition of the `$(if $(LIBUV_LIB),,$(error LIBUV_LIB not set))` statement, because it feels like a code-smelling infraction of the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

My question is: **is there a(n) (idiomatic) way to write a Makefile that enforces (fails if not true) that a variable is set for all except the `clean` target?**

Comment: Nothing to do with your question but `.PHONY: all, clean` declares target `all,` (comma included) as phony, not `all`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check which targets were invoked by looking at the `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` variable.  You probably want to fail if any target *other* than `clean` was specified, since you want to correctly handle things like `make clean all`.

So you could do something like this:

```
ifndef LIBUV_LIB
  ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
    $(error LIBUV_LIB not set)
  endif
endif
```