# Let make fail, if Makefile encounters undefined variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I had a mistake in my Makefile:

```
verify-prettier:
    $(PRETTIER) --check **/*.yaml **/*.yml
```

The var PRETTIER was not set.

The result:

```
check **/*.yaml **/*.yml
bash: line 1: check: command not found
make: [Makefile:156: verify-prettier] Error 127 (ignored)
```

I would like to get an error (which does not get ignored), if I accidentaly have an undefined variable.

Is there a way to configure make accordingly?

Version: GNU Make 4.3

We don't need to support other make implementations.

I know this, but I want it to fail, not just a warning.

```
MAKEFLAGS=--warn-undefined-variables
```

With other words: It would be nice to have something like `set -u` on the shell (Treat unset variables as an error when substituting).

**Update**, since this seem to be unavailable up to now, I created a feature request: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?63737

Comment: There is no option in GNU make that will generate a fatal error when an empty variable is referenced.  There is only `--warn-undefined-variables` which will generate a warning, but not an error, and it only warns on _undefined_ variables, not _empty_ variables (these are not the same thing).

Comment: @MadScientist thank you for your comment. I made my question more precise now.

Comment: OK, but I already gave you the answer :).

Comment: Just another point of order: GNU make invokes `sh` (some systems, like Red Hat, will link `sh` to `bash` but others will not); neither `sh` nor `bash` (by default) will expand advanced wildcards like `**`.  To the shell this is identical to `*`.  So likely your `**/*.yml` is not doing what you think.

Comment: @MadScientist prettier.io parses this glob expression, so it does work.

Comment: I don't know what prettier.io has do to with it, and it depends on what you mean by "work".  The expression `**/*.yml` is identical to running `*/*.yml` if you use the default `sh` and `bash` settings.  If that's what you want, then it works (but you're probably better off just using `*/*.yml` to avoid confusion).  Test: `/bin/sh -c 'cd /tmp && mkdir -p foo/bar && touch foo/foo.yml foo/bar/bar.yml && echo **/*.yml'` will print only `foo/foo.yml` not both `foo/foo.yml` and `foo/bar/bar.yml`.

Comment: @MadScientist `$(PRETTIER)` is the path to the prettier command line tool. The `**` does not expand, and this is intentional (you can check this via `echo **/*.yaml`). This means the prettier command line tool will get the string, and it will use its own globbing functions. This is not part of above question.

Comment: No.  The shell will expand the globbing for you BEFORE the program is called.  That's how all POSIX shells work.  If you want to pass the actual globbing characters to the program being invoked you need to quote them, as in `'**/*.yml'`.  I guess if the globbing string didn't match anything then the shell will pass the globbing characters but that's dangerous to rely on: you should add quotes if that's what you want.  Of course Windows `cmd.exe` works differently but you didn't say you were on Windows.

Comment: @MadScientist for me `echo **/*.yaml` returns `**/*.yaml`. The shell does not expand it. Ubuntu 22.04 with default shell (bash). No special config. What does your system return?

Comment: I mentioned this in my previous comment.  The way globbing works in POSIX is that the shell will try to expand the globbing.  If it matches something, then that thing is passed to the command.  If it doesn't match anything, then the glob is passed to the command.  So if you run `echo **/*.yml` and there's a file that matches `*/*.yml` in your directory, that file will be passed.  If there's no file that matches `*/*.yml`, then the string `**/*.yml` will be passed.  It's dangerous for your build system to rely on what files exist or not so if you want the glob to be passed you should quote it.

Comment: Plus, by quoting it everyone reading your command will understand what you are trying to do (pass the globbing chars to the command).  Else they will be confused as to why you have no `.yml` files in your build system.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858261/how-to-abort-makefile-if-variable-not-set  ?

Comment: @StoneThrow I prefer a global solution (like `set -u` on the shell). I don't want to use an "if" for every place where I use a variable in a Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments there is no way as of current (4.3) GNU Make versions. And any addition is likely to take forever before reaching the general public (WSL still stuck at 4.2.1!!!).

I can think of a few crutches that might work depending on circumstances:

- Pass `--warn-undefined-variables` to make, then pipe output to e.g. `grep` testing absence of the warning message. Suitable for build automation where command line length and complexity doesn't matter, less so for interactive use.
- Have blocks of `ifndef` and `error` at the end of the makefile. You'll need a specific block for each variable, however this isn't too far off how unit tests work and those are generally accepted :-)
- Default initialize to something that will fail. In the case of `$(PRETTIER)` you could initialize it to `false`, silently eating any arguments and returning failure. Feasibility depends on how the variable is used. Works well for a variable used as a command, might get trickier for arguments though I'm sure some hack ought to work (because how hard can it be to *intentionally* write crashing code).