# Looping over ifndef/endif constructs in a Makefile

Tags: loops, makefile, environment-variables

I'm trying to write a Makefile rule that checks multiple environment variables to ensure that they are defined. This is close to [Makefile variable as prerequisite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728810/makefile-variable-as-prerequisite) but I'm trying to loop over multiple variables. In other words, I'm trying to write this more concisely:

```
check-env:
ifndef ENV1
    $(error ENV1 is undefined)
endif
ifndef ENV2
    $(error ENV2 is undefined)
endif
ifndef ENV3
    $(error ENV3 is undefined)
endif
```

I've tried to use `foreach` without success, since it looks like `ifndef` is evaluated before the foreach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Makefile:

```
variables := a b c

fatal_if_undefined = $(if $(findstring undefined,$(origin $1)),$(error Error: variable [$1] is undefined))
$(foreach 1,$(variables),$(fatal_if_undefined))

all:
```

Running:

```
$ make -f Makefile.sample
Makefile.sample:4: *** Error: variable [a] is undefined.  Stop.

$ make -f Makefile.sample a=10 b=2
Makefile.sample:4: *** Error: variable [c] is undefined.  Stop.

$ make -f Makefile.sample a=10 b=2 c=5
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```