# How to check whether a given Python Environment is a PipEnv

Tags: python, pipenv

currently PipEnv can be used in a directory to check whether we have a corresponding pipenv environment or not (e.g. `pipenv --py`).
Is there a similar API to determine whether a given interpreter is a pipenv?
Wanted to check this before posting an issue on the Pipenv repo.

Answer (score 7):

From within a Pipenv shell, you can run 'pip -V' which will show you the path to the pip version you're using -- which will include the virtual environment path, and the Python interpreter.

For example:

```
pipenv shell
```

Produces:

```
Spawning environment shell (/bin/bash). Use 'exit' to leave.
~/$ . /home/<username>/.local/share/virtualenvs/projects-6W-pCI0A/bin/activate
```

Then, from within the Pipenv shell, running

```
pip -V
```

Gives:

```
pip 10.0.1 from /home/<username>/.local/share/virtualenvs/projects-6W-pCI0A/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Of course, your username would replace `<username>`, and your current working directory would replace mine (`projects`)

Answer (score 3):

You might need more accuracy than the given answer in a Makefile or as part of a build process, because the user could be using `virtualenv` or `pyenv`.

When you run `pipenv shell`, I noticed an environmental variable gets set: `PIPENV_ACTIVE=1`

After exiting the shell with `exit`,
`PIPENV_SHELL` will be unset.

So in a Makefile (this may be gnu-make specific syntax), you can add a target:

```
guard-%:
    @ if [ "${${*}}" = "" ]; then \
        echo "Run pipenv before command" \
        exit 1; \
    fi

evaluate: guard-PIPENV_ACTIVE # evaluate model
    python evaluate_model.py
```

```
$ make evaluate
Makefile:18: *** Run pipenv shell before command.  Stop.
```

Note: `make` requires tabs not spaces so copying you'll have to replace.

`guard-%` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7367903/1340069